# Is it possible to use multiple LTM8049 in parallel?

Tags: switching-regulator

Is it possible to use multiple [LTM8049](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltm8049.html) Dual SEPIC or Inverting μModule DC/DC Converters in parallel in order to further reduce noise, increase output current, and spread heat on the PCB? It is possible for more conventional regulators like the [LT3045](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt3045.html), but I could not find any such reference for a μModule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but beware of beat frequencies, hence the SYNC pin. That's what it is there for otherwise additional filtering may be required since high frequency switching noise can travel straight through the converters into the other converter. There are more pitfalls than with parallel linear regulators.

Comment: That makes sense, and I found an example in the datasheet for the LTM8045. Do you know of any evaluation board or reference circuit with schematics that would outline how filtering should be implemented? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It's just the same type of filtering you would use for high frequency noise and ripple that the SMPS cannot reject placed at the SMPS input to isolate their inputs from each other, It might not matter as much if your parallel SMPS have a common output since their noise gets mixed together anyways. Be cautious about mismatched voltage references in that case though just like linear regulators.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much, this is really helpful.